# ¿Cómo quitar barra de notificaciones?

Tags: android

Quiero crear una aplicación de pantalla completa y he buscado en Internet y todas las opciones que me dan ninguna me sirve, ya intenté esto en el android manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

y solo me quita la barra de acciones, más no la de notificaciones que es la que necesito quitar.

Tambien probé esto en código java pero la app automaticamente se cae:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Agregué una respuesta, en la documentación se comenta como realizar esto, aunque la documentación oficial tiene un error =-(, agrego la información correcta @JohanBerrio Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te refieres a la barra de status (status bar)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa la documentación de [**Barra de Estatus**](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status) , **aunque en realidad la documentación es incorrecta** debe ser:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
```

y no

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
```

**Para versiones 4.1 y posterior** usa el siguiente script el cual debe llamarse antes de cargar el layout mediante `setContentView()` :

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   }
```

Ejemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Si la versión android es menor que Jellybean, usa este llamado para esconder la barra de estatus.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       ...
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Para versiones anteriores a 4.0 la documentación sugier definir el siguiente tema en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

---

Como una opción que sugiero es crear un tema dentro de tu archivo `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppThemeNoBar"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

y este tema llamarlo desde tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    ...
     android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar">
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Funciona de maravilla, pero como hago si quiero que funcione desde la version 3.0 en adelante por ejemplo?, porque defini el tema en en manifest asi como me dijiste y se cae la app

Comment: revisa la última opción que agregué.

Answer (score 0):

prueba

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: acabe de probar, y la app se sale inmediatamente

Comment: @JohanBerrio es que esto funciona solo para versiones 4.0 o anterior

Comment: o buen punto @Jorgesys talves necesites especificar la versión que estas usando para que te pueden ayudar mas fácilmente

Comment: Pues la idea es que funcione para versiones 4.0 en adelante, lo estoy probando en mi telefono que es 5.1

Comment: encontré esta respuesta en stackoverflow en ingles talves te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android