# Android: Activity con bordes redondeados

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy intentado hacer que mi activity principal, la cual maneja fragments, tenga bordes redondeados, un claro ejemplo es esta imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podria logar yo eso? estube intentando con esto que encontre en la misma pagina [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072045/how-to-get-rounded-dialog-theme-for-activity).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

    <solid android:color="#565656" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="6dp"
        android:left="6dp"
        android:right="6dp"
        android:top="3dp" />

</shape>
```

Pero no estoy pudiendo hacer nada, no muestra absolutamente nada... no se si estoy haciendo algo mal, o algo le falta, PERO, si no lo uso como STYLE y si como BACKGROUND si me lo muestra,con la diferencia que en ves de tener las esquinas en color negro (simulando que es pantalla apagada) me las muestra en color blanco...

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias!

Comment: Puedes ver esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners) por si es lo que buscas.

Comment: Se puede con shape. Muestra el código xml de la activity ó content main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para lograr lo que deseas necesitas un [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#layerlist-element) ya que necesitas 2 [shape](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#shape-element), este archivo se guardará dentro del directorio `/drawable` de tu proyecto, por ejemplo `layout_background.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#AAFFAA"/>
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Este [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#layerlist-element) contiene 2 shapes una para el fondo de color negro y otra que contiene el color verde y tiene bordes redondeados.

El [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#layerlist-element) debes llamarlo desde el archivo layout que carga tu `Activity` (mediante el método `setContentView(archivo layout)`) y agregalo de esta forma, ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    ...
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/layout_background">
```

De esta forma obtendrás la aactvity:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

También si lo deseas puedes esconder la barra de estatus

[como quitar barra de notificaciones?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/187331/como-quitar-barra-de-notificaciones/187333#187333)

Comment: SOS UN GENIO!!!!!, muchisimas gracias, me sirvio a la primera y quedo genial!

Comment: Un placer ayudar, @LcsGrz saludos!