# Bordes con radio en android

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una duda, quiero poner en un `LinearLayout` un `background` que sea una imagen y quiero que solo las esquinas inferiores sean redondeadas. Encontré esto:

```
<item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@null" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
            <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

El problema con esto, es que las cuatro esquinas estan redondeadas (yo solo quiero las dos de abajo) y que si pongo esto en el `android:background="@drawable/border"` no puedo añadir la imagen. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

A modo ilustrativo, esto es lo que quiero pero que tenga una imagen de fondo en vez de color:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pregunta.... ¿ quieres que el linearlayout tenga un aspecto rectangular con esquinas redondeadas o que tenga un aspecto totalmente circular?

Comment: quiero que tenga más un aspecto cuadrado con los bordes inferiores redondeados @iqanansoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te paso un ejemplo de uno que hice y es lo maximo que podras hacer con shapes....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#616161" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp" android:topRightRadius="20dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:left="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="12dp" android:topRightRadius="12dp" android:bottomRightRadius="12dp" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

te explico este "shape" esta formado por dos rectangulos , uno dentro de otro, a los que se le ha redondeado las esquinas con las propiedades de la etiqueta "corners"

¿ y para que hay dos rectangulos? pues para conseguir el efecto de un borde alrededor, ya que el rectangulo interior se separa del exterior una distancia de 4dp, haciendo un efecto visual de borde, ya que si el rectangulo exterior tienen un background negro , el borde sera negro...

este codigo lo debes meter en un archivo xml. y guardarlo en la carpeta  "drawable", y tratar con este archivo como si fuese una imagen, por ejemplo asignarlo al background del linearlayout

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el background para definir el borde redondeado:

```
  android:background="@drawable/border"
```

y para la imagen puedes usar el atributo `android:foreground` , por ejemplo:

```
  android:foreground="@drawable/myimage"
```

---

Si deseas solo definir como background algo similar a :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes usar un shape, `border.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
android:topRightRadius="3dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"/>
<gradient
android:angle="45"
android:centerX="35%"
android:centerColor="#ffe7a61a"
android:startColor="#ffedaa19"
android:endColor="#ffda9c18"
android:type="linear"/>
<padding
android:left="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"/>
<stroke
android:width="1dp"
android:color="#ffe7a61a"/>
</shape>
```

y definirlo como fondo a tu layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/border"
```

Te sugiero revisar también:

[Android: Activity con bordes redondeados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189371/android-activity-con-bordes-redondeados)

[¿como puedo lograr esto con el editText?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99627/como-puedo-lograr-esto-con-el-edittext/99729#99729)

Comment: No funciona, ya que al hacerlo como dices los bordes redondeados desaparecen.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo actualice la respuesta,saludos.